# Facing Error While Installing Wordpress in Local Server

Tags: wordpress

I have installed Wordpress in local server, have changed the name of the file from wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php and have included the name of the database, user id and password.

But getting this weird message when I am trying to access the wordpress

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'localhost' (10061) in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\localdev\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1452
>
> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\localdev\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\localdev\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1482
>   Error establishing a database connection
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database
>   server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is
>   down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password? Are you sure
>   that you have typed the correct hostname? Are you sure that the
>   database server is running? If you're unsure what these terms mean you
>   should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can
>   always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Comment: hello anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

My programmer had the same problem on Windows/MAMP. We have solved it by adding port to database host:

Eg. `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889');`

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because you haven't configured mysql credentials required to connect.
You need yo edit the wp-config.php file
[More info in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)